# Read directly a file within a Zip file - Java

Tags: java, zip

My situation is that I have a zip file that contains some files (txt, png, ...) and I want to read it directly by their names, I have tested the following code but no result (NullPointerExcepion):

```
InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/resouces/zipfile/test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

*resources* is a package and *zipfile* is a zip file.

Comment: Yea, thats definitely not going to work.

Comment: you need java.util.zip http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Comment: Is the zip file on the classpath?? It needs to be

Comment: @chrislhardin: you are right, if I add **zipFile.zip** to the classpath it works fine, so it is also a solution (+1)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you can be sure that your zip file will never be packed inside another jar, you can use something like:

```
URL zipUrl = Main.class.getResource("/resources/zipfile.zip");
URL entryUrl = new URL("jar:" + zipUrl + "!/test.txt");
InputStream is = entryUrl.openStream();
```

Or:

```
URL zipUrl = Main.class.getResource("/resources/zipfile.zip");
File zipFile = new File(zipUrl.toURI());
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipFile);
InputStream is = zip.getInputStream(zip.getEntry("test.txt"));
```

Otherwise, your choices are:

- Use a ZipInputStream to scan through the zip file once for each entry that you need to load. This may be slow if you have a lot of resources, unless you can reuse the same ZipInputStream for all your resources.
- Don't pack the resources in a nested zip file, and just inline them in the jar with the code.
- Copy the nested zip file into a temporary directory, and access it using the ZipFile class.

Comment: +1, using the ZipFile class to get then entry directly is much more efficient than scanning the entire stream.

Comment: Can you explain more your first line (_if you can ..._)

Comment: Sure. The code examples won't work if your zip file with resources is contained within a jar. By that I mean that the zip file must be a real file on the file system, and not a JAR entry.

Comment: How this can be done, I mean how to make it a real file when I want to generate the jar of my project? any resources are welcome also!

Comment: It's hard to say, without knowing how your project will be deployed. If there's a directory on your classpath, that contains a subdirectory called resources, which in turn, contains your zip file, that could work (you might need to  change `Main.class.getResource("/resources/...")` to `Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/...")`). If it were me, I'd probably package the resources in the same jar as the code, so I didn't have this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach is definitely not going to work. You made up an arbitrary 'access' scheme and used it in a class that has no idea what you are trying to do. What you ***can*** do is use a [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) to read the entry you are looking for:

```
URL zipFileURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("zipfile.zip");
InputStream inputStream = zipFileURL.openStream();
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);

ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

do {
    zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    if(zipEntry == null) break;
}
while(zipEntry != null && (! "textfile".equals(zipEntry.getName()));

if(zipEntry != null ) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

This is adhoc code, fix it up to do what you need. Also, there might be some more efficient classes to handle Zip files, for example in the Apache Commons IO library.

Answer (score 0):

What is the path of the test.txt within the zip file?  You need to use the path within the zip file to read this file.   Also make sure that your zipfile is in the classpath.  In fact, you can bundle this in a jar file.