# How to open a file that is inside an archive?

Tags: javafx, media-player

I have a JavaFX application that makes heavy use of different media files for displaying information. Problem is, all those files are contained inside a .zip archive. How do I access those files and consequently play them? This is my current MediaPlayerManager class.

```
public class MediaPlayerManager {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Media media;

    public void init(File file) {
        media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(false);
        mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    }

    public void play() {
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

This is the method in my Controller class that should be able to find a file inside the archive and play it.

```
public void playbackAudioFile(String audioPath, String audioName) {

    // audioPath is the path to archive which contains audioName

    MediaPlayerManager audioClip = new MediaPlayerManager();

    // Code missing for playing audio files inside .zip

    System.out.println("Playing sound...");
    audioClip.play();
    System.out.println("Sound played!");
}
```

Comment: Can you just bundle the media files in the jar file, along with the application, instead?

Comment: I cannot, because the user provides an archive that contains such files when he's already using the application.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [Read directly a file within a Zip file - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399448/read-directly-a-file-within-a-zip-file-java), you can refactor your `MediaPlayerManager` so that it accepts a String form of a `URL` directly:

```
public class MediaPlayerManager {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Media media;

    public void init(String url) {
        media = new Media(url);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(false);
        mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
    }

    public void init(File file) {
        init(file.toURI().toString());
    }

    // ...
}
```

and now do

```
public void playbackAudioFile(String audioPath, String audioName) {

    // audioPath is the path to archive which contains audioName

    MediaPlayerManager audioClip = new MediaPlayerManager();

    String zipURL = new File(audioPath).toURI().toString();
    String jarURL = "jar:" + zipURL + "!" +audioName ;

    audioClip.init(jarURL);

    System.out.println("Playing sound...");
    audioClip.play();
    System.out.println("Sound played!");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. My path String that gets passed to media looks like "_jar:file:/home/valrog/dev/audio/notifications.zip!test.mp3_". Could this be the problem?