# How read a json file inside a zip maven dependency

Tags: java, json, maven, zip, artifact

I have a Java project that needs to depend on a ZIP file which is produced by another project. That 'other project' is not under my control. The ZIP file contains a Json file that I need to read from my project.

I currently create a dependency on the ZIP artifact like this:

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>myComponent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>zip</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

This zip file contains the following:
myFolder/myFile.json

I tried using getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myFolder/myFile.json"), but it returns null.

How can I read this file?

Thank you in advance!

I tried use getClass().getResourceAsStream() in order to access to the file contained in the zip file, but I always get null.

Comment: maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399448/read-directly-a-file-within-a-zip-file-java

Comment: ZIP Files are not support on class path... that's the reason why you can't read it via getResourceAsStream. The other project should change to provide correct dependencies (which are jar files) which can contain resources like a json file or alike...

Comment: Formatting can be improved

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I fixed the issue uncompressing the zip dependency using a maven plugin:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-zip-artifacts</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/zip-resources</outputDirectory>                         
                    <includeTypes>zip</includeTypes>                            
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This makes that the content of the zip dependency is uncompressed and put into classes folder (in this case, under a folder called zip-resources), and therefore, having them in the classpath.